# Traversing python list

Tags: python

I have 500 records in my database and I am loading all of them into a python list of dictionary elements.(25 key value pairs)

I am calling a method that traverses all the dictionary elements in the list and performs some action on each record. While traversing, I have noticed that after traversing half of the elements, logic is exiting the method and restarting again for the next half.

I tried to put it as a example. (I can't copy the exact code as it is not possible)

Ex:

```
def loadrec():
  reading from database and appending rows to a global list(mylist)

def myrun():
  print "****** Execution Started **********"
  for row in mylist:
    doing some operations and printing a string

if __name__=="__main__":
i=0
while (i>=0): #This never ends(to make the script run forever)
   loadrec()
   myrun()
   print "****** Execution Ended ************"



Result:


****** Execution Started **********
printed 250 records
****** Execution Ended ************


****** Execution Started **********
printed 125 records
****** Execution Ended ************


****** Execution Started **********
printed 62 records
****** Execution Ended ************

****** Execution Started **********
printed 31 records
****** Execution Ended ************

****** Execution Started **********
printed 15 records
****** Execution Ended ************

****** Execution Started **********
printed 7 records
****** Execution Ended ************

****** Execution Started **********
printed 1 record
****** Execution Ended ************
```

I am not sure why it is processing only half of total records every time.
But, at the end, it is processing all the records.

I have tried checking if there is any issue with python list maximum size or memory, but none of them seem to be a possible scenario.

Would be glad to know any hint of what could have been the reason.

Comment: You have a problem with your code, but you can't show us the code, but still want someone to pinpoint the issue? Going to be difficult. For all we know, you've explicitly coded a break condition for when you get halfway through the list. Unlikely, but how can we tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild stab in the dark here.

You are doing something like this:

```
def myrun():
    print "****** Execution Started **********"
    for row in mylist:
        #Some processing here
        myList.remove(row)
```

You cannot mutate a list that you are iterating over.  This would account for only processing half the list each time. You will need to refactor your code. Without you showing us your code, I'm not even going to try and do the refactor.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for taking that wild stab. That hit me correctly. Yes, you are correct. In one my methods i am removing the item that I am iterating from the list. As you mentioned, it is processing only half items bcos of that. Now, I have commented my code, and it is traversing full elements now without making it half.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I am not able to share the code due to some privacy restrictions. Anyways, you are able to pinpoint the issue. Thanks for that. I would like to know the reason why python processes only half the elements every time when there is remove logic. Also, since I need to remove the item from list (as per logic), do you think that keeping old code will cause any issues. (At the end, I am still processing all the elements, but the processing is happening in halves every time).

Comment: https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/ This will explain it better than I can in the space here. If you just want to process each item in the list, there is no reason that you should keep the `while` loop. Surely you want the script to end at some point?

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. I am clear now. As for your question " Surely you want the script to end at some point?" -- Yes, I do not want to stop my script as  it continuously monitors some jobs in database(There is a method in the script which does that) and process them. It should never stop even though there are no jobs.